# mysql/c++ connector error: libmysqlcppconn.so.7: cannot open sahred object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, bash

I know there is a lot about this on the internet and I have tried most of it without luck. Most solutions says that en environment variable is missing aka (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) which i pointed it to the file in user and root but it still does not pick it up. I am not sure what exactly is looking for the library or how to fix this??

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
ldd output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb97ff000)
libmysqlcppconn.so.7 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f002fdb3000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f002fb9c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f002f7dd000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f002f5c0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f002f2c3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f00300c7000)
```

Comment: Did you set it *before* running the executable? And are you *sure* it's set as an environment variable?

Comment: what is the output of `ldd executablecfile.c`

Comment: its all good except for that library, see edit please

Comment: Have you tried looking for the file in your system(so by doing a find) and then adding the path onto your ld_library_path?

Comment: Tell us exactly *how* you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: yes thats what I did, i did find /* -name libmysqlcppconn tehn I found it in /usr/local/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7 and I did export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7

Comment: Well, that's not a library **path** now, is it?

Comment: does it need to go in $PATH or $LD_LIBRARY_PATH... google suggested teh second one and that's what I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you *correctly* set the library path...

If your library is at `/usr/local/lib/libmylib.so.4` and your program is `./myprog`:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib ./myprog`

Comment: Thanks man, I found this as well might help somebody later... http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: if anyone wants to run their program without everytime specifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH then see this https://serverfault.com/questions/372987/centos-usr-local-lib-system-wide-ld-library-path